# Почему в файле формируемом PHPExcel выводится "ЛОЖЬ" вместо русского текста?

Tags: php, строки, phpexcel, кириллица

Я уже извелся весь:

```
function shortName($fullName) {

    $res = explode(' ', $fullName);
    return $res[0] . " " . $res[1][0] . '. ' . $res[2][0] . '.';
}
```

Выводит "ЛОЖЬ"...

Код вывода (использую PHP Excel):

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $off_y + count($persons), 'Начальник ___________ ' . $this->shortName($reslist->branch_manager));
```

Пример данных: Иванов Иван Иваныч

Comment: А где кусок кода, который что-то выводит?

Comment: Ну и было бы неплохо получить данные, которые вы скармливаете функции.

Comment: Код: `$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $off_y + count($persons), 'Начальник ___________ ' . $this->shortName($reslist->branch_manager));` Данные: `Иванов Иван Иваныч`

Comment: @ИльяБизунов, добавьте, пожалуйста, все это в вопрос

Comment: Копайте в сторону PHPExcel. Ваш код должен выдавать нормальную строку(т.е. проблема не здесь).

Comment: На мой взгляд, причина в том, что строка $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__)).ничего не делает,  а ЛОЖЬ в файле PHPExcel.php осталась с прошлых времён. Она могла там появиться, например, при изменении кодировок.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала прочитайте документацию: [**Доступ к символу в строке и его изменение**](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).
По поводу вашего кода: функция `shortName` вопреки вашим ожиданиям ничего не возвращает.

---

Допустим, есть переменная

```
$test = 'Some text';
```

Запись вида

```
echo $test[0];
```

Выведет на экран `S`. Почему это происходит? По сути, запись вида `$string[int]` является синтаксическим сахаром для записи вида `substr($string, int, 1);`

Это все прекрасно работает с однобайтовыми кодировками. Этому условию удовлетворяет, например, текст на английском. В случае с кириллицей необходимо использовать аналог функции [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php) — [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php) для работы с многобайтовым кодировками.

Еще раз: в вашем случае, придется явно использовать функцию `mb_substr`. Увы, никакой магии для русского текста не предусмотрено.

Вот ваша функция с минимальными изменениями:

```
function shortName($fullName) {

    $res = explode(' ', $fullName);
    return $res[0] . " " . mb_substr($res[1], 0, 1) . '. ' . mb_substr($res[2], 0, 1) . '.';
}
```

---

Я бы вам рекомендовал проверять существование ключей с индексом 1 и 2 с помощью [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-key-exists.php), если вы не делаете этого до передачи строки в функцию `shortName`.

---

При написании ответа использовался ответ на вопрос: **[Strings as arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17193651/2486051)** на StackOverflow.

---

**update**: добавлен минимальный пример для демонстрации работы функции

```
<?php
/** Подключаем PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

function shortName($fullName) {
    $res = explode(' ', $fullName);
    return $res[0] . " " . mb_substr($res[1], 0, 1) . '. ' . mb_substr($res[2], 0, 1) . '.';
}

// Подготавливаем данные
$string = 'Начальник ___________ ' . shortName('Иванов Иван Иванович');

// Создаем объект PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Добавляем данные
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, $string);

// Сохраняем в формате Excel 2007 с тем же именем, что и PHP файл
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение с индексами, я и подумать не мог, что у них такое странное поведение. Но Ваша функция все равно, как и моя, выводит "ЛОЖЬ".

Comment: Удостоверьтесь, что вы передаете текст в кодировке UTF-8. Файл с кодом тоже должен быть в кодировке UTF-8.

Comment: Проверил все кодировки. В БД - utf-8, исходник - utf-8, в момент передачи функции параметра - строка тоже в utf-8. Везде utf-8 =(

Comment: И все же внимательно проверьте данные. Собрал минимально возможный рабочий пример с использованием вашей логики и обновленной функции.

Answer (score 2):

Причина нашлась в неожиданном месте...

```
/** Подключаем PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

function shortName($fullName) {
    $res = explode(' ', $fullName);
    return $res[0] . " " . mb_substr($res[1], 0, 1) . '. ' . mb_substr($res[2], 0, 1) . '.';
}

// Подготавливаем данные
$string = 'Начальник ___________ ' . shortName('Иванов Иван Иванович');
print($string."<br>");

// Создаем объект PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Добавляем данные
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, 3, $string);

// Сохраняем в формате Excel 2007 с тем же именем, что и PHP файл
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('simple.xlsx');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

А теперь сравните файлы.

P.S. Заодно отмечу, что проблема двухбайтовой кириллицы решается также путём конверсии формата в однобитовый. Технология перехода туда-обратно работает, например, при [адаптации wordwrap() под кириллицу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469212/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%83/469321#469321)

Comment: Уточните, в чем же по-вашему, все-таки, причина?

Comment: Потому что второй файл не обрабатывается ВООБЩЕ. Сотрите ЛОЖЬ и запустите снова.

Comment: Дело в том, что я не наблюдаю указанного поведения в выложенном мной примере. Я бы не стал выкладывать не протестированный кусок кода. Хорошо, если это действительно решит проблему.

Comment: Надо почистить и закрыть Excel - файлы, а потом обновить PHP-страницу. Если моя гипотеза подтвердится, то копать дальше.

Comment: ЛОЖЬ и у меня как-то раз мелькнула, но я её очистил. Это когда я с кодировками игрался.

Answer (score 1):

Тест к ответу VenZell.

```
function shortName($fullName) {
   $res = explode(' ', $fullName);
  return ($res[0] . " " . mb_substr($res[1],0,1) . '. ' . mb_substr($res[2],0,1) . '.');
}
print(shortName("Иванов Иван Иванович"));
```

Результат: `Иванов И. И.`
А в исходном виде функция выводила не "ЛОЖЬ", а крокозябры.

P.S. Неожиданно проходит

```
function shortName($fullName) {
    $res = explode(' ', $fullName);
    return ($res[0] . " " . substr($res[1],0,2) . '. ' . substr($res[2],0,2) . '.');
}
```

с правильным ответом.

Comment: Вы изменили поведение функции автора. Его функция преобразовала ФИО в фамилию и инициалы. Ваша же просто поставит точки после имени и отчества. Индексы не лишние. Автор таким образом хотел обратиться к первым буквам имени и отчества.

Comment: Вы полностью правы.

Comment: Теперь это просто тест Вашего ответа

Answer (score 1):

Я так и не смог разораться, в чем была проблема. Но переделав функцию `shortName`, все заработало. Видимо проблема была именно в ней. Вот код рабочей функции:

```
function shortName($fullName) {
    return preg_replace('/(\w+) (\w)\w+ (\w)\w+/iu', '$1 $2. $3.', $fullName);
}
```

Comment: Похоже, причина - во вложении функции str_replace в функцию save. Я исправил свой ответ.

Comment: Так обрабатывался файл - или нет?